# Cannot get broadcom wifi adapter working

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, broadcom

I'm trying to get my broadcom wireless adapter working, ubuntu MATE 18.04.

Running `lshw -C network` shows e.g.

```
product: BCM4321 802.11a/b/g/n
logical name: wlp3s0
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271
```

Running

```
rfkill list all
```

Does not show my wireless being soft or hard blocked.

Running `lspci` shows that my hardware is Broadcom Limited BCM 4321 802.11 a/c/g/n (rev 05)

So the proprietary driver seems to be installed, hardware is fine AFAICT, but running `sudo iwlist wlp3s0 scan` yields no results, and the 'wireless networks' option on the network applet is greyed out. I don't hide my SSID, it just seems like I can't connect to any networks. Wrong driver perhaps? How can I tell?

Also, the computer is a 2009 Mac Mini if that matters.

Comment: I don’t think bcmwl-kernel-source is correct for your device.

Comment: @chili555 I hit the "Install 3rd party drivers" option during the install, that's the one that it installed. Since `apt list | grep bcm` didn't turn up anything else I didn't think too much about it. I'll look up my actual hardware in the list and see if I can get the correct driver installed.

Comment: @chili555 it was the `firmware-b43-installer`. Thanks for that link, it didn't turn up in my google searches and the stack exchange auto-suggester didn't bring it up when I was writing the question.